# Node - subquery in mysql insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, subquery

I'm using the [`https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library.

How can I do an `INSERT` with a subquery?

For example:

```
connection.query(
    INSERT INTO foods (name,category) VALUES (?,?)`,
    [
       `pizza`, 
       `SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'italian'`
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for a subquery, but you can use placeholders in the subquery:

```
connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO foods (name,category) VALUES (?,(SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = ?))',
    [
       `pizza`, 
       'italian'
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Needless to say, much better than workaround I had found.

Comment: The subquery may need to be wrapped in parenthesis ... in case anyone else can't get this working right away.